# Calling function using post inside another jquery post in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to call  function using post  inside another jquery post like below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.post("/testcall1",
    function(data){
        $('#testDiv1').html(data);
      $.post('/testcall2',function(data){$('#testDiv2').html(data);});
    });
</script>
```

From the above piece of code, I have to call one after another not at the same time, Will that work first, if yes will that work in all kind of browser like IE7, IE8, FF,Safari, Chrome

Comment: It should work in all of those browsers.

Comment: so here,after getting the response form "testcall1",the second call "testcall2" will happen...right?

Comment: may I recommend to rename the 'data' variable? Using double variable names can cause confusion & other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/, the function will be called when 'success' is returned from the first call, yes it will be called after the first, but only when it is success.. And it should work on all the browsers.